# Rails 4: prepopulate form with param from URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, parameter-passing

In my Rails 4 app, I have a `Calendar` and a `Post` models, using `shallow routes`:

```
resources :calendars do
  resources :posts, shallow: true
end
```

A calendar `has_many` post and a post `belong_to` a calendar.

A new post object is created via the `Posts#New` view, with the following form:

```
<%= form_for [@calendar, @calendar.posts.build], html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :date, "DATE & TIME" %>
    <%= f.datetime_select :date %>
  </div>

  [...] # Truncated for brivety

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit @post.new_record? ? "CREATE POST" : "UPDATE POST", :id => :post_submit %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

In certain cases — but not all — I want to prepopulate the date field of the form with the params passed through the URL.

I have been able to pass a date through the URL with the following link:

```
<%= link_to '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i>'.html_safe, new_calendar_post_path(@calendar, date: date) %>
```

This link gives me a URL of the following kind:

```
http://localhost:3000/calendars/6/posts/new?date=2015-11-12
```

From there, how can I prepopulate the form?

And most importantly, how can I do so **ONLY** when a date is passed through the URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should prepopulate new Post data in Post controller on `new` action

```
class PostsController << ApplicationController
  ...
  def new
    if (date = params['date']).present?
      @post = @calendar.posts.build(date: date)
    else
      @post = @calendar.posts.build
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

And in your view

```
<%= form_for [@calendar, @post], html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :date, "DATE & TIME" %>
    <%= f.datetime_select :date %>
  </div>

  [...] # Truncated for brivety

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit @post.new_record? ? "CREATE POST" : "UPDATE POST", :id => :post_submit %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

Comment: +1 also wanted to note the conditional can probably be removed: `@post = @calendar.posts.build(date: params[:date])` should work for both cases, it will just set the date to nil if not supplied in the querystring (which is probably the default value anyhow)

Answer (score 1):

Off topic: you might want to use the block syntax for `link_to` instead of using html_safe?

```
<%= link_to new_calendar_post_path(@calendar, date: date) do %>
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Absolutely. I had built this page before learning what you recommend and have not updated my code yet. Thanks for noticing.